# Bringing activity back from foreground

Tags: android, background, notifications, foreground

I stuck in a problem. 
Suppose there is an activity A
now, user press Home key, and put A into background.
now, after remaining in background for a while, it will generate a notification.
On clicking on that notification, it will bring back the exact same activity which was in the background. 
Like, after pressing home key, if user start the application again by clicking on the icon or from the recent launched history, then android re-opens exactly last activity in it's previous state.
Here, I dont want to detect which was the last activity. My activity is fixed, I just want to bring it back at its previous state on clicking on the notification ? 
Is that possible ? how to do that ? 
here is my code for notification,

```
    private void generateNotification(Context context, String message, String data) {   
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.notification, message,  System.currentTimeMillis());

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MenuActivity.class);        
    //notificationIntent.setFlags(Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("data",data);
    notificationIntent.putExtras(bundle);

    //Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID++;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, context.getString(R.string.app_name), message, PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR));
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` instead of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY`.